# Can the topic は be ordered after other words or phrases?

Tags: syntax, particle-は, word-order

Consider the English sentence "I ate an apple in the train.".
This can be translated to

> わたしは　でんしゃで　りんごを　たべました。

It is possible to re-order the location and objects in this sentence.
For instance, one might also say

> わたしは　りんごを　でんしゃで　たべました。

Pre-question: Is this a usual sentence structure?
Is this sentence

- good,
- uncommon, but understandable or
- grammatically wrong?

(If this changes emphasis is not part of this question.)

My understanding is that this can be a valid sentence, but may sound odd for native speakers.

---

Can the topic also be re-ordered like this?
For example, consider this sentence:

> りんごを　わたしは　でんしゃで　たべました。

Is this sentence

- good,
- uncommon, but understandable or
- grammatically wrong?

Comment: JFYI, all of these are grammatical and share the same meaning. The first one is natural, the second one is less common, the third one is rare but okay in poems/lyrics.